# Determining resource requirements to run an application to a system

Tags: asp.net, requirements

The application to be created **using the requirements below** is a website made from ASP.NET pages.

I need to know the **software requirements** as well as **minimum hardware requirements** for the application to run to a system.

*Contents of the website include graphic games (hangman, matching game etc.) which follows the exact same requirements below.*

SOFTWARE REQUIREMENTS:

1.Framework: At least **.NET 4.5 or higher**

2.Database: At least **Microsoft SQL Server 2012 or higher**

3.Development Tools: At least **Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 or higher**

4.Design: Must use **HTML5** or **equivalent TEMPLATES** on designing the applications

5.Validation: All validations and checking must be implemented by using either **JavaScript** or **jQuery/jQueryUI** or **AJAX control toolkit**.

OTHER REQUIREMENTS:

1. Application: Must be a website made from **ASP.NET** pages
2. Host: Must be hosted under **IIS 7.5 or higher**(Internet Information Serivices)
   and **NOT IIS Express**.
3. Language: Must be written in **ASP.NET C# Web Forms** (aspx pages).
4. Connection String: Must use SQL Authentication and NOT Windows Authentication
   to SQL Seriver
5. Database: Transaction of data on database server must be **ALL** written under
   MS SQL Server Stored Procedures
6. Database Storage: Data must be stored in a database engine. Compact SQL is 
   **not allowed**.
7. Classes: **LINQ** or **Entity Framework** or other object-relational mapper products
   are NOT ALLOWED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hardware requirements are more centered around SQL Server here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.110).aspx

1GB RAM unless running SQL Express (in which case 512B)

Min 1.4 GHZ x64 Processor
The big question here is - is this for an assignment or a production system. Must this scale What's the load? Those are all questions that will determine what hardware you need. If this is a basic demo or assignment, near any modern system will work.